# Strategies to find memory leak in AIR app with native extension

Tags: flash

**Background:**

I'm working on an Adobe AIR app that has many facets. I'm looking for strategies to find memory leaks.

Broadly speaking, the EXE contains an embedded JVM, and an AIR Native Extension for Windows (using C). So there are many moving parts.

As one example, I'm using [MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/home) which traces either the AIR runtime (or the Flash Player... I'm not sure which). We've used it to find one leak (regarding listeners in ActionScript).

I'm also monitoring the EXE via PowerShell and trying to match memory jumps with log files.

**Questions:**

- How can I monitor an embedded JVM, that is launched via C in an AIR ANE?
- Any other strategies? I'm treating this as a "whiteboard" question; this is why it's not on Stack Overflow.